# Wordpress Loop Limit

Tags: wordpress, loops

I have a custom post which has 41.300 different posts, i am trying to loop over all records like this:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'zip_codes', 'posts_per_page' => 45000);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

But it does not work, it only works when i reduce the posts_per_page to 21000 or less, like this:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'zip_codes', 'posts_per_page' => 21000);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Any advice guys? Thanks

Comment: Should be use pagination

Answer (score 0):

Any advice? Don't.

Let me elaborate, you're trying to load 40,000+ posts into memory. Every title, html content block, etc etc is being loaded. This is (almost?) assuredly burning through all of your available server resources.

Depending on what you're actually doing in the `while`, loop, you'll want to consider doing this in chunks/batches. PHP is single threaded by default, so it will continue through a loop as a single executed process. What this means is that you can pull in 100 posts, and then run a new query on the next 100 when that's done.

If you're modifying the posts, consider using SQL instead, it can be much more efficient than dealing with the PHP and WordPress overhead. If that's not possible, considering using the `'fields' => 'ids'` argument available in [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) so you're only pulling the post IDs into memory instead of all of the content.

If you're displaying posts, consider using the `paged` attribute and only loading 100 or whatever makes sense in your context, and use AJAX or pagination to load in more when they're required.

Otherwise, expanding on my first point, change the `posts_per_page` to like `100` and query it in blocks inside a `for` loop, using the `offset` argument to modify the posts pulled in per loop.

```
for( $i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++ ){
    $offset = 100 * $i;
    $args = array('post_type' => 'zip_codes', 'posts_per_page' => 100, 'offset' => $offset );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $query->have_posts(){
        while( $query->have_posts() ){ /* Do the thing */ }
    } else {
        break; // We ran out of posts, stop doing the `for` loop.
    }
}
```

Either way, without actually batching this, depending on what you're doing, and *how* you're spawning this (spawned as a process from cron this won't be subject to the same limitations as an HTTP request, for example), this is going to be intensive and will be taxing on your resources specifically memory, CPU usage, and your `max_execution_time` directive.